# Why are PDF in pdfinfo keywods run together

Tags: hyperref

My document includes the commands

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage [colorlinks] {hyperref}
\hypersetup {
   colorlinks,
   pdfinfo={
      Author={Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz}
      Subject={Topology}
      Title={A Proposed Unification of Manifolds and Fibre Bundles}
   }
}
\begin{document}
  \null
\end{document}
```

The the author in the created PDF metadata is "Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz Subject=Topology Title=A Proposed Unification of Manifolds and Fibre Bundles"; the other two fields are blank.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Option `pdfinfo` expect key value pairs, separated by commas. The latter, the commas between the key value pairs are missing. Then `Author` is the key and the remaining part is the value. With commas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage [colorlinks] {hyperref}
\hypersetup {
   colorlinks,
   pdfinfo={
      Author={Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz},
      Subject={Topology},
      Title={A Proposed Unification of Manifolds and Fibre Bundles},
   }
}
\begin{document}
\null
\end{document}
```

Result with `pdfinfo`:

```
$ pdfinfo test.pdf
Title:          A Proposed Unification of Manifolds and Fibre Bundles
Subject:        Topology
Keywords:
Author:         Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz
Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref package
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.17
CreationDate:   Mon Aug 15 19:17:29 2016
ModDate:        Mon Aug 15 19:17:29 2016
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      8488 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```